# How to parse out items from a JSON array in jQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

So basically im making a call to an MVC controller and returning the results of a query in JSON format.

```
<script>
    $("#APINumber").focusout(function () {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("CheckAPI", "WellInfo")', { APINumber: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
            if (!data.isDuplicate) {
                toastr.error('API Number does not exist in the database. Please check your API Number.', 'API Number Error')
                $("#APINumber").val("")
            }
            var id = JSON.stringify(data.list);

            $.each(data.list, function (value) {
                viewModel.LeaseName(JSON.stringify(data.list[value]));
            });

            
        });

    });
```

What I want to do is pull out the value called "LeaseName" from my query. I made the $.each loop to try to parse them, but my textbox I am filling with **viewModel.LeaseName(JSON.stringify(data.list[value]));** displays the whole JSON string! See below, this is what I get.

```
{"WellKey":221622,"OperatorKey":21,"LeaseKey":519,"APINumber":"03048374","FormattedAPINumber":"030-48374","RedrillCancelFlag":"  ","WellDesignation":"518G1-34","FieldCode":"052","FieldAreaCode":"05200","FieldName":"Belridge, South","AreaCode":"00","AreaName":"Any Area","DistrictNumber":"4","CACountyCode":"030","CountyName":"Kern","LeaseName":"","WellNumber":"518G1-34","IsActive":1,"WellTypeCodeList":"","WellStatusCode":"A","WellStatusDate":"/Date(1342814313397)/","BLMInterestCode":"N","OperatorName":"Aera Energy LLC","OperatorCode":"A0610","IsCurrentActive":true,"Section":34,"Township":"28S","Range":"21E","BaseMeridian":"MD","IsBLMInterest":false,"IsEPAWell":false,"BaseOfFreshWater":"","AssignedEngineerID":-1,"IsHydraulicallyFractured":true,"AbandonedStandardStatusCode":"Not Abandoned","DirectionalStatusCode":"Directionally drilled","LocationDescription":"Fr SW cor 582 N 405 E","Elevation":"592 KB","IsDryHole":false,"Version":4,"Well2Version":3}
```

I dont want the whole this in my textbox, I just want to display a SINGLE value from that JSON data.

Any help would be awesome!!!!

**EDIT**

Tried using this

```
            $.each(data.list, function (value) {
                var json = JSON.stringify(data.list[value])
                console.log(json["WellKey"]);
            });
```

I get undefined in the console...

**EDIT 2**

Solved! No need for loops, I guess using $.getJSON already stringifies it, all I need to do to access my data was using something like data.list[0].FieldName

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: Is that not the stringification of the object located at data.list[value]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need:

```
json["LeaseName"]
```

See jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5BhWr/

However, please be aware that LeaseName has **no** value in your returned json.

**Update**

Looking at your code I believe that this will output your value:

```
data["LeaseName"]
```

As you are within a `getJson` call, the `data` variable will already be json.

If you take a look at this fiddle, it outputs a value in the same manner only `WellKey` as that has a value:

http://jsfiddle.net/5BhWr/2/

Comment: Thats a great approach, however for some reason im getting back "undefined" in my console window.

Comment: Have you seen the fiddle? Give me a min, I'll take a look.

Comment: Run this fiddle and you will see it output the WellKey in a div from the json..http://jsfiddle.net/5BhWr/1/

Comment: I think from your code that data["LeaseName"] should do it for you.

Comment: Your JSFiddle works great, thats exactly what I want! I keep getting 'undefined in the log...even if I just use  data.list["WellKey] or any other way....check my post for my edited foreach loop. Maybe im doing it wrong

Comment: I think the data variable is already json, I don't think you need to do the stringify. You should just be able to do data["WellKey"]. Give that a try. I've updated the question to clarify it a bit. Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: Try this: $.each(data, function (value) {
                console.log(value["WellKey"]);
            });

Comment: Or this: $.each(data.list, function (value) {
                console.log(value["WellKey"]);
            });

Comment: I just keep getting undefined for everything. Its weird, my code basically matches yours. My json variable holds the same data, yet json["AnythingHere"] yields undefined...Im gonna keep plugging away at it...maybe go get a coffee lol. Ill let you know if I have anything else. Really appreciate your help too, I think im on the right track...gotta love programming :)

Comment: OH MAN!! I got it :) all I had to do was console.log(data.list[0].FieldName); Didnt even have to stringify it, or loop it, DOH! Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Why use the indexer rather than then more standard `.`? THe code is perfectly valid and semantically equivalent to `data.LeaseName`

Comment: @RuneFS Only preference really, you don't have to use the indexer. I prefer it in case the json ends up having spaces in. i.e. if I'm using a look of keys coming from an unknown source. As far as I know bracket notation is a standard too, there are just two ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

From what you write it seems that you have a stringify too many. Assuming that

```
{"WellKey":221622,"OperatorKey":21,"LeaseKey":519,...}
```

is the value of

```
data.list[value]
```

then simply do

```
viewModel.LeaseName(data.list[value].LeaseName);
```

Comment: The weird thing is that if I try to do data.list[value].LeaseName...the .LeaseName part doesnt even show up in the list of options to choose from.

Comment: Using a combo of your answer and hutchoids, I came up with console.log(data.list[0].FieldName). No needs for loops or strigifying. Thanks!